# errors happen when I import another module's actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing a single-paged application. Since this application updates pages on rootApp, some actions of rootApp are planned to be used by other pages, e.g. redirectPageTo. I directly use import and export to try to directly dispatch the action of RootApp, but the compiling error happens. The error is something undefined, but actually it's well defined in the same file. Is there any correct way to do this? Any ideas are welcome.

```
//this page is the page other than RootApp; here is the LoginPage reducer
import {redirectPageTo} from './RootAppAction.jsx';//import actions, with this line, errors like defaultState undefined happens

const defaultState={(some states declaration)};
export function updateLoginPageState(state={},action) {
  ...
  dispatch(redirectPageTo("HOMEPAGE"));//use other module's action. Can I use it in this way?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the root cause may relate to that I put the reducer and the action codes in the same file.